# We have got about 30 predefined webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink

How could we freze one predefined webpart and reuse it with some ofproperties. When we have got let example Quick Links how to add in Sharepoint Online Sharepoint Framework another links to predefinied links?

Comment: Not sure can it be done in SP online, But on prem you could configure web part, export it (then you can rename it) and re-upload it to the web part gallery. But that would not block users from removing any predefined links from web part.

Comment: It works with modern pages ? or only with classical pages ?